# Test if a variable is a Shapely geometry

Tags: python, shapely

I want to test if a variable is any kind of Shapely geometry. The variable might also be a list or a datetime. I can test for all kinds of Shapely geometries separately, like:

```
if type(var) in [shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString, shapely.geometry.point.Point, ...]:
   print(True)
```

But is there something like an `is_shapely()` function?

Answer (score 8):

The classes should all inherit from `BaseGeometry`:

```
if isinstance(var, shapely.geometry.base.BaseGeometry):
    print(True)
```